# Dominated convergence theorem for complex-valued functions?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose there is a sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$.

I've previously used the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) for interchanging the limit and the integral in $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx$ when $f_n(x)$ was a real-valued function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.  Per the usual steps, I would find an integrable function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f_n(x)|<g(x)$ for all $n$ in the index set and $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  I would thus justify $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$.

I am wondering what happens when $f_n(x)$ as well as the limiting function $f(x)$ are complex-valued, i.e., $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, but their integral is real-valued. How do I safely interchange the limit and the integral?

**Specific example**

The semi-classical theory of optical homodyne detection (see section on homodyne detection, for example, [here](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-453-quantum-optical-communication-fall-2008/lecture-notes/MIT6_453s08_lec08.pdf)) involves subtracting two independent Poisson random variables.  The resulting random variable, when appropriately normalized, converges to a Gaussian random variable in distribution.  I am wondering if a stronger result holds, where the density function converges pointwise to the Gaussina density as well.

Consider Poisson random variables $N_-$ and $N_+$ with respective means $a^2_-=\frac{1}{2}(a_S-a_L)^2$ and $a^2_+=\frac{1}{2}(a_S+a_L)^2$.  Here, $a_S$ is the amplitude of the signal field, and $a_L$ is the amplitude of the much-stronger local oscillator field.  $N_-$ and $N_+$ are the photon counts at the two arms of the homodyne detector.  To recover the signal at the output, we subtract the two counts (and normalize), which effectively cancels the local oscillator field.

Thus, consider the random variable $A=\frac{N_+-N_-}{2a_L}$.  Its characteristic function is just the product of the characteristic functions of the Poisson random variables $\frac{N_+}{2a_L}$ and $-\frac{N_-}{2a_L}$:

$$\phi_A(t)=\exp\left[a_+^2(e^{it/2a_L}-1)+a_-^2(e^{-it/2a_L}-1)\right],$$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$. Now, taking the limit as $a_L\rightarrow\infty$ yields:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\phi_A(t)&=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[a_+^2(e^{it/2a_L}-1)+a_-^2(e^{-it/2a_L}-1)\right]\\
&=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[a_+^2\left(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\right)+a_-^2\left(-\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\right)\right]\\
&\begin{aligned}=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2+2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)\left(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\right)\\\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad+\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2-2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)\left(-\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\right)\right]\end{aligned}\\
&=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[ita_S-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^2a_S^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-1})\right]\\
&=\exp\left[ita_S-\frac{t^2}{8}\right],
\end{align}$$
which is the characteristic function of Gaussian random variable with mean $a_S$ and variance $\frac{1}{4}$, thus proving convergence of $A$ to Gaussian in distribution.

Now, applying the inverse Fourier transform to $\phi_A(t)$ yields the density function of $A$. I am wondering if it's Gaussian in the limit of large $a_L$.  It would be if:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left[-it(x-a_S)-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^2a_S^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-1})\right]dt=\\
\qquad\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\left[-it(x-a_S)-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^2a_S^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-1})\right]dt.\end{align}$$

Can someone help?

Comment: There's no problem with DCT for complex-valued functions. See any book on measure theory... (or for that matter show for yourself that DCT for complex-valued functions is immediate from DCT for real-valued functions).

Comment: The main problem is that I don't know measure theory all that well (though I never took a formal course in it, I know probability theory pretty well at the graduate engineering student level).  In this context, I am not sure how function $g$ would look like.  Is $|f_n(x)|$ simply the magnitude of a complex-valued function $f_n(x)$ and $g(x)$ has to be greater than that magnitude for all $x$?

Comment: You might consider _learning_ some measure theory... Yes, DCT looks exactly the same: If $f_n\to f$ almost surely, $|f_n|\le g$ and $\int g<\infty$ then $\int f_n\to\int f$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich what if the dominating function $g$ is also complex valued ? Then $|f_n|\leq g$ doesn't make sense, perhaps better ask $|f_n|\leq |g|$ where $|.|$ is the usual complex modulus

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín (i) There's no need to speculate on what the statement of DCT should be. It's a hugely standard thing, easy to find (and the standard statement _is_ exactly as I said). (ii) Saying "but what if $g$ is complex valued, then $|f_n|\le g$ doesn't make sense" doesn't quite make sense. True, if $g$ is complex valued then it is not true that $|f_n|\le g$. So the theorem simply does not apply - there is simply no such thing as a complex-valued dominating function. (iii) Yes, one _could_ state it as $|f_n|\le |g|$ and allow complex-valued $g$. That version is (trivially) equivalent

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Ok, to be fair to everyone, I've just now found places online where DCT is stated only for real-valued functions. That's just stupid. Trivial proof that the real DCT implies the complex DCT: Say $f_n$ is complex-valued, $f_n\to f$ as, $|f_n|\le g$ and $\int g<\infty$. Write $f_n=u_n+iv_n$, $f=u+iv$. Then $|u_n|\le|f_n|\le g$, so the real DCT shows $\int u_n\to\int u$. Similarly for $v_n$. Hence $\int f_n\to \int f$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you are absolutely right, I don't now what I was thinking when I said that a dominating function could be complex valued, my bad !!

Comment: @M.B.M. How is it that you obtain $$
\lim_{a_L\to\infty}\exp\bigg[\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2+2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{ t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3}))+\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2-2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)(-\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3}))\bigg]
=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\bigg[ita_S-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^2a_S^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-1})\bigg]
 $$?

Comment: I tried to, but i think that was a bug Here I try again:@M.B.M. How is it that you obtain $$
\lim_{a_L\to\infty}\exp\bigg[(a_S^2+a_L^2)\big(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\big)\bigg]
=\lim_{a_L\rightarrow\infty}\exp\bigg[ita_S-\frac{t^2}{8}-\frac{t^2a_S^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-1})\bigg]
 $$???

Comment: @ConradoCosta I am not sure where in my derivation you found that expression.  In the first block of formulas of "specific example" the second equality is from Taylor series expansion of $e^x$; the third equality just plugs in the definitions of $a_-^2$ and $a_+^2$, and expands the squares; the fourth equality is just careful arithmetic -- a lot of terms cancel out; and final equality just evaluates the limit.

Comment: In the display where you calculate $\lim_{a_L\to \infty} \phi_A(t)$ I can't follow you from the third line to the fourth line (I counted 5 lines). I would write the equation down, but I am having trouble with format so the attempts are in the comments above and if you didn't find the expression $$ \exp\bigg[(a_S^2+a_L^2)\big(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2‌​}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3})\big)\bigg]$$ It is (I believe) the result of the sum of two terms in your third line. It's safe to ignore this step as you might have another way to get from line 3 to line 4.

Comment: @ConradoCosta You see, I am having trouble locating that term that you wrote down -- it's not in my calculations anywhere.  Perhaps you are confusing $a_-^2$ with $a_S^2$ and $a_+^2$ with $a_L^2$?  In that case, note the negative sign in front of $\frac{it}{2a_L}$ in the term on line 2 corresponding to $a_-^2$...  You can see that most of the terms in line 3 either combine or cancel out when you do the arithmetic...

Comment: Here:
$$\bigg[\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2+2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+{O}(a_L^{-3}))+\frac{1}{2}(a_S^2-2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)(-\frac{it}{‌​2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+{O}(a_L^{-3}))\bigg] =\bigg[(a_S^2+a_L^2)\big(\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2‌​}+{O}(a_L‌​^{-3})\big)\bigg]$$
I am using that $AC + BC = (A+B)C$ with $A = \frac{1}{2}(a_S^2+2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)$
$B = \frac{1}{2}(a_S^2-2a_Sa_L+a_L^2)$ and $C = (-\frac{it}{‌​2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+\mathcal{O}(a_L^{-3}))$ I believe $$A+B = (a_S^2+a_L^2) $$
Maybe I am missing something... what do you think?

Comment: @ConradoCosta Looks like you missed the negative sign: $\frac{it}{2a_L}\neq -\frac{it}{2a_L}$, so your $A$ doesn't get multiplied by your $C$.  It gets multiplied by $\frac{it}{2a_L}-\frac{t^2}{8a_L^2}+O(a_L^{-3})$, which does not equal your $C$.  Does that make things clear(er)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bounded convergence theorem  for each coordinate. Since $|f_n|\leq g$ implies $|\Re f_n| \leq g$ and $|\Im f_n| \leq g$ ($\Re z$ is the real part of $z $ for $z \in \Bbb{C}$, and $\Im z$ is the immaginary part of $z$)
$$\Re\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg) = \int \Re f_n(x)\, dx \\
\Im\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg) = \int \Im f_n(x)\, dx$$

Then the bounded convergence theorem yields 
$$\lim_n\Re\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg) = \int \lim_n\Re f_n(x)\, dx \\
\lim_n\Im\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg) = \int \lim_n\Im f_n(x)\, dx$$

And conclude noting that

$$\lim_n\int f_n (x)\, dx = \lim_n\bigg(\Re\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg) + i \Im\bigg(\int f_n (x)\, dx\bigg)\bigg) \\= \int \lim_n\Re f_n (x)\, dx +i \int \lim_n\Im f_n(x)\, dx $$

Comment: Thanks for writing out the answer.  I just want to make two notes: 1) it mirrors @DavidC.Ullrich's comment above, and; 2) the "local limit theorem"-like result in the example seems to hold using this flavor of DCT (one could use the same dominating function $g(t)=\exp[-t^2]$ for both real and imaginary parts since sine and cosine are bounded in $[-1,1]$).

Comment: I don't fully understand  your point 2), could you explain it in greater detail?

Comment: "Example" refers to the "specific example" I gave in my question (sorry that it's long).  Your answer allows me to interchange the limit and the integral at the very end of the "specific example."  This shows that the probability density function of the random variable $A$ (which you recover from the characteristic function using Fourier transform) approaches Gaussian in the limit (after dividing by $2\pi$, which I omitted for brevity). Convergence in probability described earlier in "specific example" is central-limit-theorem-like, while convergence of densities is "local". Does this explain?